# Plotting Particular Conic Section

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

How would I plot $-2x^2 -2y^2 = 1$ on the x-y plane ? I believe it is an ellipse, since the coefficients have the same sign, I just don't know what the major and minor axes would be nor how to plot.

Comment: Something negative or zero equals something positive ...

Comment: This equation is not solvable for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, 'cause $-2x^2-2y^2\leq0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is a [degenerate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic) conic :  $$-2x^2-2y^2=1 \iff  x^2+y^2 = -1/2$$ Can the sum of squares of two real numbers ever be negative ?

The set of points satisfying the given equation is therefore $\varnothing .$

Answer (score 0):

It is an imaginary circle.

If $both$ coordinates are imaginary, the imaginary circle has a real radius = $1/\sqrt2$,

You cannot plot it on real axes.